# Numpy append - appends columns of array values instead of a row

Tags: python, numpy, append

I have a 2 dimensional numpy array which is initialized and filled with some values afterwards. I would like to attach a new row, however, I append new rows consisting of the elements of the row that was supposed to be attached.

The initial array printout looks as follows:

```
(6404, 10300, 2, 13, 2018, 10, 1, 195.0, 1, 720, 1020, 2795, 750)
(6403, 10300, 1, 13, 2018, 10, 1, 195.0, 1, 420, 720, 3094, 675)
(6402, 10300, 3, 13, 2018, 10, 1, 195.0, 1, 1020, 1260, 99999, 99999)
(6401, 10300, 2, 13, 2018, 10, 1, 195.0, 1, 720, 1020, 2802, 750)
(6400, 10300, 2, 13, 2018, 10, 1, 195.0, 1, 720, 1020, 2867, 750)
```

I try to append a new row as follows:

```
row =  np.array([99999, 999, 0, 45, 2018, 99, 99, 60, 1, 420, 1260, 999, 920])
array = np.append(array, np.array([row], dtype=array.dtype))
```

The output looks like this:

```
(6404, 10300, 2, 13, 2018, 10, 1, 195.0, 1, 720, 1020, 2795, 750) 
(6403, 10300, 1, 13, 2018, 10, 1, 195.0, 1, 420, 720, 3094, 675)
(6402, 10300, 3, 13, 2018, 10, 1, 195.0, 1, 1020, 1260, 99999, 99999)
(6401, 10300, 2, 13, 2018, 10, 1, 195.0, 1, 720, 1020, 2802, 750)
(6400, 10300, 2, 13, 2018, 10, 1, 195.0, 1, 720, 1020, 2867, 750)
(99999, 99999, 99999, 99999, 99999, 99999, 99999, 99999.0, -97, 99999, 99999, 99999, 99999)99999)                                                    0300) 
(99999, 99999, 99999, 99999, 99999, 99999, 99999, 99999.0, -97, 99999, 99999, 99999, 99999)
(10300, 10300, 10300, 10300, 10300, 10300, 10300, 10300.0, 60, 10300, 10300, 10300, 10300) 
(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
(44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44.0, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44)
(2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018.0, -30, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018)
(99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99.0, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99) 
(99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99.0, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99)
(60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60.0, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60) 
(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1.0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
(420, 420, 420, 420, 420, 420, 420, 420.0, -92, 420, 420, 420, 420)
(1260, 1260, 1260, 1260, 1260, 1260, 1260, 1260.0, -20, 1260, 1260, 1260, 1260)
(3094, 3094, 3094, 3094, 3094, 3094, 3094, 3094.0, 22, 3094, 3094, 3094, 3094) 
(1080, 1080, 1080, 1080, 1080, 1080, 1080, 1080.0, 56, 1080, 1080, 1080, 1080)
```

I would like to attach the row as a row and don't see the bug at the moment, as I used it in the same way before.

Comment: You haven't read the append docs recently, have you?

Comment: I am just starting to use numpy, so I have to read up most of the things I do. However, it is not always easy to understand everything right away.

Comment: `np.append` has several pitfalls.  But did you pay any attention to the `axis` parameter?  But first, what is `array.dtype`?  The `() ` in the display makes me suspect it is a structured array.  Also what's `array.shape`?

Comment: Did you look at `np.array([row], dtype=array.dtype)` before trying to append it?

Comment: I initially thought the problem with `append` was that it was flattening due to the lack of the `axis` parameter.  But looking further I think the problem is with constructing the proper structured `row`.  To concatenate structured arrays, they need to have matching dtypes.  Your problem is with how you constructed that `row`.

Comment: I usually discourage the use of `np.append`.  It's poorly named and has too many pitfalls.  It's better to learn to use `np.concatenate` correctly.  That said, the use of `append` is not the problem here.

Comment: @hpaulj: Thank you for your comments, I will try using np.concatenate in the future. But for np.append: If I fix the dtype of the new row as follows `row =  np.array([9999, 99999, 0, 13, 2018, 11, 10, 60, 1, 420, 1260, 999, 920], dtype=array.dtype)`, it still doesn't work.

Comment: That's not how you construct a single element structured array.

Comment: Ok, I guess I found it... there were parenthesis missing within the square brackets `row =  np.array([(9999, 99999, 0, 13, 2018, 11, 10, 60, 1, 420, 1260, 999, 920)], dtype=jobs_sel.dtype)` Thank you :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use `concatenate` instead of `append`:

```
array = np.concatenate((array, row[None,:]))
```